# Joining 2 arrays together code improvement

Tags: php

There are 2 arrays. One that consists of Categories and one of Products. Each product pertains to its specific category. I want to join each product to its right category (a category can have multiple products). Each product that 'finds' its category will go in this category's products array.

Here's my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($prods); $i++)
{
    for ($u = 0; $u < count($cats); $u++)
    {
        if ($prods[$i]['category_code'] === $cats[$u]['category_style_code'])
        {
            if ( !isset($cats[$u]['products']) )
            {
                $cats[$u]['products'] = array();
            }
            array_push($cats[$u]['products'], $prods[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It results in something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_style_code] => GA
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [default_price] => 37.50
                            [category_code] => GA
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [default_price] => 15.00
                            [category_code] => GA
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Let's say there are many categories and many products... How would you optimize this code (or do it differently maybe there are PHP functions which could be used) ?

Edit: I also want to make the resulting array indexes be the its category code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to make it a bit better is to:

- Use foreach.
- Use category by reference.

This way the code will look like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($categories as &$category) {
        if (!isset($category['Products'])) {
            $category['Products'] = array();
        }
        if ($product['category_code'] === $category['category_style_code']) {
            $category['Products'][] = $product;
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
Having PHP > 5.5.0 you can use the following code to have the category_style_code column as key:

```
$keys = array_column($categories, 'category_style_code');
$categories = array_combine($keys, $categories);
```

This will combine an array that uses $categories as values and $keys as keys, where $keys we picked up all values in category_style_code column.

Comment: This won't work, because it'll only add a products array to the `$category` value in the iteration, not to the original `$categories` array.

Comment: Actually it's working. I'd have another request -- how can I make the key as the category_style_code instead of indexes? I tried for example
`$cats[$category['category_style_code']] = $category;` but I'd like to unset the previous key/value too.

Comment: @vanamerongen This is what I stated in the answer "use category by reference"

Comment: @DanyP To make the key to be your category_style_code column, please tell me what version of PHP you're running. The code will be very different depending on if the arrat_column function of PHP is available which is after   5.5.0

Comment: @thanpa Yeah I didn't know about using variables by reference. That's great.

Comment: @DanyP I made an edit to include what you asked here. Will you please add this in the description of the question as well so it will not be off topic?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do this:

```
foreach( $prods as $prod ){
    foreach ($cats as &$cat){
        if ( $prod['category_code'] == $cat['category_style_code'] ) {
             $cats['products'][] = $prod;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

And setting the category array key to the category code:

```
foreach( $cats as $k => &$cat ){
     $cats[ $cat['category_style_code'] ] = $cat;
     unset($cats[$k]);
}
```

I've tried that ampersand thing used in the other answer. Hopefully that works. If it doesn't there's another way.

Comment: This isn't working -- the products array isn't being shown in the updated categories array.

Comment: Great thanks :) I'd like to make the key look like the category_style_code -- so that when I use it then I can just do for example $cats['GA']. Optimally unsetting / removing the duplicate row (not keeping the number indexed keys/values)

Comment: Ah, sure, you can use another foreach loop. I'll add it.

Comment: Cool the key association part is working but not the unset. The old values are kept.

Comment: In this case without the ampersand, it works :) Thanks